Refactor an R Function to Keep Existing Behavior but Add New Methods
I'm trying to refactor a function in R. Here's an example of my function:
# Example
sum_of_array <- function(x, y) {
  return(sum(c(x,y)))
}

This function is already in use in my project's code, like so:
v <- sum_of_array(c(1,2,3), c(8,9,10))
33
v+10
43

I want to refactor the sum_of_array function to meet the following requirements:

Don't want to break the existing code. I want the return value v to behave like a numeric vector when used directly (though in my actual code it might be a data frame or something else).

Support some special functions, like:


# new 
v <- sum_of_array(c(1,2,3), c(8,9,10))
get_length(v)
# sum of all input vector length
6

Note, due to the widespread use of this function in code, I don't really want to redefine some basic functions, such as +.

There are two options for your last example to work: (1) sum_of_array has to store its input (e.g., in an atrribute of the return value) or (2) sum_of_array has to store the desired quantities (such as the input length). Which do you prefer? Option 1 is more flexible but needs more memory. There are also performance implications. Your downstream code might also be relevant as it might assume (implicitly) that there are no attributes.

Hi @Roland, I think option 2 is what I want, but what confuses me is how to do it properly without breaking the exists code, that is, other functions can use the return value of sum_of_array as before, except for the specifically custom function.

Overall, your issue isn't very well specified.
The following should work if you don't use functions that rely on v having no attributes. For example, some functions behave differently for objects and atomic vectors. Also, some functions (like +) can propagate attributes to their return value.
sum_of_array <- function(x, y) {
  res <- sum(c(x,y))
  attr(res, "input_length") <- length(c(x,y))
  oldClass(res) <- c(oldClass(res), "withpayload")
  res
}

print.withpayload <- function(x, ...) {
  attr(x, "input_length") <- NULL

  #the next line shouldn't be needed if x has other explicit classes
  attr(x, "class") <- attr(x, "class")[attr(x, "class") != "withpayload"]
  NextMethod()
}


get_length <- function(x) attr(x, "input_length")


v <- sum_of_array(c(1,2,3), c(8,9,10))
#[1] 33

str(v)
# 'withpayload' num 33
# - attr(*, "input_length")= int 6

get_length(v)
#[1] 6

v+10
#[1] 43

str(v+10)
#'withpayload' num 43
#- attr(*, "input_length")= int 6

